# AngularJS: Binding Data to Dynamically Created HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a script that dynamically creates HTML form fields. I am trying to use Angular directives to bind data. I believe the binding is not occurring because the HTML elements are not there on page load since they are being dynamically created. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="form-builder-wrapper">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" autocomplete="off">
          <ul class="handles">
              <br />
              <!--Dynamic HTML is being appended here with jQuery-->
          </ul>
          <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-20 hide" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

My jQuery is dynamically appending my HTML elements in the form above. Here is a sample element that is being appended:

```
<div class="form-group requiredField" id="element_1" data-type="textbox">
    <label for="element_label_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label" ng-bind="element_label_1">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="element_1" id="element_label_1" required="">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in my `label` field, I am attaching a `ng-bind="element_label_1"` directive. I am attempting to update the `label` with this code:

```
<p>Update Label: <input type="text" ng-model="element_label_1"></p>
```

But this is not working. It is not binding together. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the biggest problem is using jQuery to append to the DOM in an angular app. Without the html being run through `$compile` angular can't intialize any of the directives

Comment: @charlietfl I am kind of an angular newb, do you mind giving a complete code example I could use?

Comment: like @pixelbits I'm a bit reluctant without seeing some of your code. It might be easy enough to migrate, or it might be something that can be easily put into a directive where you can access angular scope to use `$compile`. If you are trying to add angular on top of a heavy jQuery page, then it might not be a good idea at all. A better outline of your development status would help determine that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding to the DOM tree after DOM load, you've likely missed the compilation/linking process that Angular does.  You'll have to manually compile and link your new elements using the $compile service.

```
 parent.append(element);
 $compile(element)($scope);
```

Comment: I am kind of an angular newb, do you mind giving a complete code example I could use?

Comment: I would, but you haven't posted enough code for me to guess on an exact solution. Can you post the code that adds the new elements to the DOM, include the ngController too